# JOIN on a String After Converted to Integer

Tags: mysql, sql, join, sql-convert

I am trying to `LEFT JOIN` on a `CHAR` after it is converted to an `INT`. Like this:

```
SELECT o.title, d.title FROM original o
LEFT JOIN directory d ON CONVERT(o.directory_index, UNSIGNED INT) = d.index
```

This gives me the correct response if the index is greater than zero. But if the index is zero or an empty string, I get duplicates of the row for every directory title:

```
o.title       (o.index)    d.title          (d.index)

"Big Boss"    "2"          "OUTER HEAVEN"    2
"Snake"       "0"          "FOX"             0
"Snake"       "0"          "FOXHOUND"        1
"Snake"       "0"          "OUTER HEAVEN"    2
"Kerotan"     ""           "FOX"             0
"Kerotan"     ""           "FOXHOUND"        1
"Kerotan"     ""           "OUTER HEAVEN"    2
```

So I added a `COALESCE` statement to convert every empty string to a `NULL` value:

```
SELECT o.title, d.title FROM original o
LEFT JOIN directory d ON CONVERT(
    CASE WHEN COALESCE(o.directory_index, '') = '' THEN NULL ELSE o.directory_index END,
    UNSIGNED INT
) = d.index
```

The `COALESCE` statement does give me the correct response (I tested the output of the function alone), but now I get `NULL` for every directory title, unless the index was set to `0`, in which case I get the same result as before:

```
o.title       (o.index)    d.title          (d.index)

"Big Boss"    "2"          NULL              2
"Snake"       "0"          "FOX"             0
"Snake"       "0"          "FOXHOUND"        1
"Snake"       "0"          "OUTER HEAVEN"    2
"Kerotan"     ""           NULL              0
"Kerotan"     ""           NULL              1
"Kerotan"     ""           NULL              2
```

What am I doing wrong?

---

As suggested, I got rid of the `COALESCE` statement, and swapped it out for a `NULLIF` statement:

```
SELECT o.title, d.title FROM original o
LEFT JOIN directory d ON CONVERT(
    NULLIF(o.directory_index, ''),
    UNSIGNED INT
) = d.index
```

But I am met with the same result as if I had the `COALESCE` statement.

I created a [Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/374e39/2) of the examples I have provided, and strangely enough it gives me my desired result. But this is not the result I am getting in Workbench. The server is running an older version of MySQL (5.1 I think?) could that be the problem?

---

Okay... so I am pretty embarrassed. I was banging my head against the wall all day yesterday. Then I come in this morning and take a look at it, it turns out what was supposed to be `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... = d.index` was set to `LEFT JOIN ... ON ... = d.title`. I am going to up-vote everyone on this thread. But I hope you all down vote me and/or mark the question to be closed.

Comment: what's directory_index? it would helps if you add schema

Comment: Seems odd to me that you're joining to `o.` on both sides of the equal.  `o.directory_index = o.index`.... shouldn't one of those by d?  Regardless of the casting and case joining to table original twice will not give you results from directory d

Comment: @xQbert Ah, yes, my mistake, it should be `d.index`. I am trying to fix up the question to make it more clear, I will change that too.

Comment: Your `CASE` is too complicated, it's the same as `CONVERT(
    NULLIF(o.directory_index, ''),
    UNSIGNED INT)`

Comment: @dnoeth Ah, thank you, that is much shorter (I am a little new to SQL). But sadly I still get the same result.

Comment: Can you show DDL & some rows in a fiddle? Without details about dataypes it's hard to say what's wrong.

Comment: In the sample output, should the `(o.index)` column actually be `(o.directory_index)`?

Comment: Do you have indexes on the columns in your real table that you didn't replicate in the sqlfiddle?

Comment: @Barmar I am not sure what you mean. The index in the real table represented by `direct` has indices from 0-9. The matching "directory_index" in the table represented by `original` has values from "00"-"09", or an empty string. There are plenty of other fields in both tables, but I don't think they would affect this statement. Or could they?

Comment: I don't mean columns **named** index, I mean does your schema have database indexes on those columns? That could alter how the join is performed, which could explain why you see a difference in your database from sqlfiddle.

Comment: @Barmar Oh, sorry, no. The `original` table does have a primary index, and an index that combines the "title" with some other columns, but none relating to the `direct` table. The `direct` table does not have any indexes.

Comment: Then it sounds like it may be a bug in the old MySQL version you're running, which they've fixed.

Comment: @Barmar Great, well, I have no control over that. So I guess my quest ends here. Thank you for all of your help.

Comment: did you try my query in the answer see if that would get rid of the bug... i am making directory_id -1 when it's NULL or ''

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`COALESCE` does not replace an empty string with NULL values. Rather, it returns the first non-NULL expression in the list.

To replace an zero length string with a NULL, you could use a variety of expressions...

```
 NULLIF(expr,'')

 IF(expr='',NULL,expr)

 CASE WHEN expr = '' THEN NULL ELSE expr END
```

And to convert a string (CHAR, VARCHAR) expression to a numeric value, you could use as shorthand:

```
expr + 0
```

But that's not guaranteed to return an UNSIGNED INT, or even an integer value.

---

**ORIGINAL ANSWER** below

What's missing here are the definitions of the `directory_index` column from `directory` table and the `index` column from the `original` table.

What are the datatypes of those columns? Are either of them nullable, or is either unique? Is there a foreign key relationship?

It's not possible to answer your question "What am I doing wrong" if we don't know what it is you are trying to achieve.

At first glance, the join condition looks way more complicated than it needs to be.

Can you explain why *this* doesn't (or wouldn't) work?

```
SELECT o.title
     , d.title
  FROM original o
  LEFT
  JOIN directory d 
    ON d.directory_index = o.index
 ORDER BY ...
```

What *problem* are you trying to solve by adding the functions in the join condition?

You seem to be aware of datatype conversions (from CHAR to INT, etc.) And you seem to be aware that MySQL will do a lot of those datatype conversions  implicitly.  And you can make those datatype conversions explicit, and can override what MySQL would do by default.

In a numeric context, MySQL will evaluate an empty string as a value of 0, not NULL. As a simple demonstration,

```
SELECT '' + 0
```

But, again, what is it that you are trying to achieve?

This is where a small amount of sample data, and the expected output would clarify the specification.

How to go about achieving that result is really going to depend on the actual datatypes of the columns used in the expressions, and what you want returned.

Any "try this" suggestions we make would just be guesses, not answers.

Answer (score 1):

It's kind'a confusing since your query looks like it's looking o.directory_index...but your data you show o.index (could that be your mistake?)
Anyways, try this one.

```
SELECT o.title,d.title
FROM original o
LEFT JOIN directory d
ON (CASE WHEN o.directory_index IS NULL OR o.directory_index = '' THEN -1
         ELSE CONVERT(o.directory_index,UNSIGNED INT)
    END) = d.index;
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0c96a/1)
If CONVERT() is the bug in older MySQL Version...maybe try CAST()

```
SELECT o.title,d.title
FROM original o
LEFT JOIN directory d
ON (CASE WHEN o.directory_index IS NULL OR o.directory_index = '' THEN -1
         ELSE CAST(o.directory_index as UNSIGNED INT)
    END) = d.index;
```

Since there's a bug with CONVERT() to UNSIGNED INT....why not try CONVERT() to CHAR... like this (might not work but worth a try).

```
SELECT o.title,d.title
FROM original o
LEFT JOIN directory d
ON o.directory_index = CONVERT(d.index,CHAR);
```

[sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e0c96a/6)

Comment: This gives me the same result (with `CAST` or `CONVERT`)

Comment: see bottom of my answer for another method to try..i am thinking if CONVER() to UNSIGNED INT doens't work is buggy, why not try CONVERT(d.index,CHAR) instead...give it a try and let me know if it works for ya

Comment: Sadly, it was unnecessary, please see the edit I made to my question. It worked with just the `CONVERT(NULLIF(o.directory_index, ''), UNSIGNED INT)` method. I am sorry for taking up your time, but I appreciate your help.